# Convert multiple columns with same name to one column in c#

Tags: c#

I have a data table like below:

```
field_1   field_1  field_2  field_2 

1         2         3        4
```

Now I  want to convert it to:

```
field_1      field_2 

1             3
2             4
```

using c#.

I tried to use this code to add columns header, but i cannot import rows to it:

```
private DataTable test(DataTable dispTable)
    {
        DataTable outputTbl = new DataTable();

        int index = 0;
        // Get list values of datatable
        var stringArr = dispTable.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

        // Add column headers
        outputTbl.Columns.Add("hidden_col");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dispTable.Columns)
        {
            if (index % 2 == 0) //dispTable always contain 1 pair of column with same name
            {
                // Create a new column
                outputTbl.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName);
            }

            // Moving to next col
            index++;
        }

        return outputTbl;
    }
```

How to do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What data table? What are the rules of conversion? Do you have 2 columns with the same name?

Comment: atleast show what you have tried so far, its very irritating to answer a question that does not show any hard work behind it !

Comment: @Szymon: yes, it always contain 2 columns with the same name, and the total number of columns is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public void Test(DataTable indata)
        {
            DataTable outdata = new DataTable();
            ArrayList columns = new ArrayList();

            // create a outdatatable to contain only distinct coulmn names
            foreach (DataColumn dc in indata.Columns)
            {
                if (!columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
                {
                    columns.Add(dc.ColumnName);
                    outdata.Columns.Add(dc);
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in indata.Rows)
            {
                DataRow outdr = outdata.NewRow();
                outdr["field_1"] = dr["field_1"] + " " +dr["field_1"]; // dont think it is possible to have two coulmns of same name
                outdr["field_2"] = dr["field_2"] + " " + dr["field_2"];
            }
        }
```